# Multiple frames within Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-layout

I am experimenting with Tkinter to build a simple UI. This will contain a similar structure to the below:

- Menu

  - Settings
  - Action1
  - Etc...

I want Menu to be my main frame, and there to be some general stuff on there and then buttons to the other frames.

I have been using some code I found here as a baseline but my amendments failed to work as expected. For example, why do the Label's and Entry's I place not show?

Code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Name")
width=400
height=500
screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
root.geometry(alignstr)
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

f1 = tk.Frame(root)
f2 = tk.Frame(root)
f3 = tk.Frame(root)
f4 = tk.Frame(root) 

title = tk.Label(f1, text = "Title", background = '#3b5997', foreground ="white", font = ("Times New Roman", 25))
title.place(x=100,y=20,width=200,height=50)

eg1 = tk.Label(f1, text="Text :")
eg1.place(x=10,y=195,width=70,height=25)
eg2 = tk.Label(f1, text="Text")
eg2.place(x=290,y=195,width=70,height=25)
eg3 = tk.Entry(f1, width=20)
eg3.place(x=100,y=195,width=200,height=25)

raise_frame(f1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Menu is on the `Tk` window not on the `Frame`.

Comment: Are you able to please expand further? for example, eg1 is placed on f1, no?

Comment: Just by looking at the code, because you have not used any geometry manager on the frames, its not being placed anywhere.

Comment: Also since you are using `place`, the widgets do not _really occupy_ any space on the frame but the widgets exist on the frame and maybe because of that, `frame` does not have any default size, you need to give in `width` and `height` to the frames.

Answer (score 0):

I have used .grid() and pack() but never used place however I found the issue.

you need to use .place() for frame f1 as well, after the content that you want in that frame.

```
import tkinter as tk

def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Name")
width=400
height=500
screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
root.geometry(alignstr)
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

f1 = tk.Frame(root)
f2 = tk.Frame(root)
f3 = tk.Frame(root)
f4 = tk.Frame(root) 

title = tk.Label(f1, text = "Title", background = '#3b5997', foreground ="white", font = ("Times New Roman", 25))
title.place(x=100,y=20,width=200,height=50)

eg1 = tk.Label(f1, text="Text :")
eg1.place(x=10,y=195,width=70,height=25)
eg2 = tk.Label(f1, text="Text")
eg2.place(x=290,y=195,width=70,height=25)
eg3 = tk.Entry(f1, width=20)
eg3.place(x=100,y=195,width=200,height=25)


f1.place(x=100,y=20,width=1000,height=900)  #  <-------------like this 

raise_frame(f1)
root.mainloop()
```